# How to extract elements from a filename and move them to different columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a filenames which I converted into a list. The list has the following elements:

```
list = ['15253_Variation.JPG',
 '15253_Variation_Tainted.JPG',
 '15253_Variation_O2_Saxophone.PNG',
 '15253_Variation_O2_Saxophone.jpg',
 '15253_Variation_O2_Saxophone_reference.png',
 '15253_Variation_Side1.JPG',
 '15253_Variation_Side2.JPG']
```

My goal is to extract elements from this list and fill out a dataframe, which should look like this:

[image]

LINK TO THE GOOGLE SHEETS CONTAINING THE IMAGE ABOVE: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kuX3M4RFCNWtNoE7Hm1ejxWMwF-Cs4p8SsjA3JzdidA/edit?usp=sharing

WHAT I'VE DONE SO FAR is the following code:

```
Obj = pd.DataFrame(data = list, index = None, columns = ['file'])
new_list = []
for i in Obj['file']:
       new_list.append(i.split('_'))
```

But, this one does not leave empty spaces thus not doing what I needed.

Thank you very much in advanced.

Comment: With the current amoutn of information in your question this is simpy not possible. We can not know what element of what filename belongs into which column. For "Side.." you even switch them to the front. What rules do you apply to sort the O2  value of `'15253_Variation_O2_Saxophone.PNG'` into Oxygen but the followint value saxophone not in location? You would need to _at least_ define how we can know which part of what name goes where based on whatever. [edit] your post to add  these infos.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thanks Patrick. The location column is actually empty but was just included incase any future filenames would have a location, which would be the last element before the extension. Hope I made sense.

Comment: no much. Why does "O2" belong to Oxygen and not in say Location2 or Issues or Location or Musical Instrument. Why does saxophone go into musical Instrument and not into Ref - etc. You need all those rules in place to do anything sensible with your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per number of the comments.  It's a pain because the tokens in the filename are not fully fixed format.  Quite a lot of conditional logic

1. have defined two additional lists `mi` instruments and `oxygen` whatever it is.
2. first pass is in building `dict` that is pandas standard format
3. then work through conditional logic after have base data frame

```
# don't name it list - it override python list()!
l = ['15253_Variation.JPG',
 '15253_Variation_Tainted.JPG',
 '15253_Variation_O2_Saxophone.PNG',
 '15253_Variation_O2_Saxophone.jpg',
 '15253_Variation_O2_Saxophone_reference.png',
 '15253_Variation_Side1.JPG',
 '15253_Variation_Side2.JPG']

issues = ["Tainted","Perfect"]
mi = ["Saxophone"]
oxygen = ["O2"]

# first pass using dict/list comprehensions
df = pd.DataFrame({"filename":{i:f.split(".")[0] for i,f in enumerate(l)},
             "Number":{i:f.split("_")[0] for i,f in enumerate(l)}, 
              "Name":{i:f.split("_")[1].split(".")[0] for i,f in enumerate(l)}, 
              "Location2":{},
              "Issues":{}, "Oxygen":{},"Location":{}, "Musical Instrument":{},
             "Ref":{}, 
              "Extension":{i:f.split(".")[1] for i,f in enumerate(l)}})

df = df.assign(**{
    # list of tokens for checking fixed lists against
    "Tokens":lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda s: s["filename"].split("_")[2:], axis=1),
    "Issues":lambda dfa: dfa["Tokens"].apply(lambda s: s[np.where(np.isin(s, issues))[0][0]] 
                                           if np.isin(s, issues).any() else np.nan),
    "Musical Instrument":lambda dfa: dfa["Tokens"].apply(lambda s: s[np.where(np.isin(s, mi))[0][0]] 
                                           if np.isin(s, mi).any() else np.nan),
    "Oxygen":lambda dfa: dfa["Tokens"].apply(lambda s: s[np.where(np.isin(s, oxygen))[0][0]] 
                                           if np.isin(s, oxygen).any() else np.nan),
}).assign(**{
    # let's do tokens again minus ones already placed
    "Tokens":lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda s: [t for t in s["filename"].split("_")[2:] 
                                             if not(t==s["Issues"] 
                                                    or t==s["Musical Instrument"]
                                                   or t==s["Oxygen"])], axis=1),
    "Location2":lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda s: s["Tokens"][0] if len(s["Tokens"])>0 
                                      and "Side" in s["Tokens"][0] else np.nan, axis=1),
    "Ref":lambda dfa: dfa.apply(lambda s: s["Tokens"][0] if len(s["Tokens"])>0 
                                      and "Side" not in s["Tokens"][0] else np.nan, axis=1)

}).drop(columns=["Tokens","filename"])

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
Number       Name Location2   Issues Oxygen  Location Musical Instrument        Ref Extension
 15253  Variation       NaN      NaN    NaN       NaN                NaN        NaN       JPG
 15253  Variation       NaN  Tainted    NaN       NaN                NaN        NaN       JPG
 15253  Variation       NaN      NaN     O2       NaN          Saxophone        NaN       PNG
 15253  Variation       NaN      NaN     O2       NaN          Saxophone        NaN       jpg
 15253  Variation       NaN      NaN     O2       NaN          Saxophone  reference       png
 15253  Variation     Side1      NaN    NaN       NaN                NaN        NaN       JPG
 15253  Variation     Side2      NaN    NaN       NaN                NaN        NaN       JPG
```